# 404 errors while hosting multi page react app on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I want to host a multi-page react app on gh-pages. I've got links to different pages on my navbar, it routes properly to the links on homepage. But for different pages, I'm getting a 404 file not found error.

Comment: Sometimes it really can be annoying ..GitHub is case sensitive so try writing the exact name  .. for eg iMg.jpg can't be read as img.jpg in github pages!

Comment: Can you provide additional information, perhaps an example link if its public, or example source code that we can look at?

Comment: https://github.com/jaishh5/rm-final this is the link to the repo

Comment: https://youtu.be/uTofiLVM3mg

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, if you are using BrowserRouter, try switching to HashRouter, that fixed it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).